# capture SSID in wireshark or tshark

Tags: bash, wireshark

Im new in tshark...below code is a part of a code that captures SSID(NAME of access point) and takes average of its RSSI(power of signal).
I need someone to explane what this line does exactly???

```
tshark -i prism0 -Y wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x08  -T fields -e wlan.sa -e prism.did.rssi -e wlan_mgt.ssid -a duration:1 > air1.txt
```

the main code is:

```
#Main shell script for generating appropriate data for histograms
#$1 (first command line parameter): run length
#$2 (second command line parameter): Target SSID
#Usage: should be run as root, example:
# ./histscan.sh 10 Computer

let i=0;
while [ "$i" -lt "$1" ]; do

let i="$i+1";

tshark -i prism0 -Y wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x08  -T fields -e wlan.sa -e prism.did.rssi -e wlan_mgt.ssid -a duration:1 > air1.txt

echo "SSID       AVG-RSSI" > mean.old

RSSI=$(cat air1.txt | grep $2 | cut -f2 | ./rssiMean.sh | cut -d'.' -f1)
if [ -z "$RSSI" ]; then let RSSI=-100; fi
let RSSI="$RSSI+100";
echo $2 "       " $RSSI >> mean.old

cp mean.old mean.rssi

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tshark command you included here will set up and start a packet capture. Here are the parameters the line specifies.

-i prism => indicates that the capture should be done on the interface named prism0

-Y wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x08 => specifies a display filter. So, this capture will only print out 802.11 frames that are access point beacons.

-T fields => The output will contain just the data fields you specify with all of the -e options

-e => The specific fields to print out. In your case, it will be the WLAN source address [basically the MAC of the access point that sent the beacon], the RSSI, and SSID fields.

-a duration:1 => The capture will run for 1 second

air.txt => Output of the tshark command will be directed to this file.